# Stack two navigation bars in bootstrap 3

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

How would you arrange the HTML in order to show two stacked navigation bars with bootstrap 3? In ASCII art, the layout should look like:

```
+-------+
| a b c |
+-------+
| d e f |
+-------+
|  ...  | <- rest of the page
```

Where `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, etcetera are buttons.

I would like to show this layout also on wide screens, it is just a way of grouping controls. Note that saying *two stacked toolbars* i mean two visual navigation bars, because from the point of view of the classes i would expect a common parent `navbar` class, otherwise fixed positioning may lead to overlap the two navigation bars.

Comment: There is no reason to down-vote this. It would be beneficial to everyone to leave a comment or ask for clarification instead, not just down-voting and leaving.

Answer (score 1):

No answers, i had to go with trial and errors and my best guess at the moment is the following:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="#">a</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">b</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">c</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="#">d</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">e</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">f</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/danse/nKCXE/14/) (widen the page or hit `Ctrl + Shift + Return` to load a draft on a new page, because the preview is narrow and the toolbar may collapse)

Even if i am not interested in the collapse behaviour, i had to add the `collapse` classes in order to align the buttons horizontally, otherwise each one of them had been stacked vertically.

Comment: is it just me, or you can't see any output in demo page

Comment: just edited the answer for this, it is because of collapsing behaviour, widen the page or load a draft